# What are the Benefits of using django rest framework over plain django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have a Django service setup for my current project it receives inputs from Angular2 frontend and gives back data in XML format. Do I get any special benefits if I move it to Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and take a look at its documentation. If you don't think that you will need the stuff that it provides, then you won't get any "special benefits". This basically applies to any kind of framework you are planning to use.